# show a div on a button click using angularjs and HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to show a div on a button click using angularjs and HTML
I am learning angularJs.
I want to design a webpage in which on click of 'Add' button a div(EmployeeInfoDiv) is shown.
When I fill the textboxes in it and save it the data should reflect in table within the div(EmpDetTable).

Here is the HTML page code:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
 <div ng-controller="EmpDetCtrl">       
    <div ng-model="EmpDetTable" class="container body"  ng-hide="addEmp">

        <label class="TabHeadings">Employee Details</label>
        <div class="EmployeeInfo">

            <table ng-model="Employee" border="1">
                <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Designation</th><th>Salary</th></tr></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                        <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{emp.desg}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button ng-model="AddEmp" ng-click="ShowAddEmployee()">Add</button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    <div ng-model="EmployeeInfoDiv" class="popover right EmployeeInfo" style="width:1500px;"  ng-show="addEmp" >
     <label class="TabHeadings" style="width:830px;">Employee Details</label>

    <div class="EmployeeInfo">
            <table>
                <tr><td><label class="table_label">Name:</label></td><td><input type="text" ng-model="name" class="textbox"/></td>
                <td><label  class="table_label">Designation:</label></td><td><input type="text" ng-model="desg" class="textbox"/></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <div ng-model="botton_container">
                <button ng-model="save" class="save_buttons" ng-click="SaveData();">Save</button> 
                <button ng-model="cancel" class="cancel_buttons"  ng-click="ShowViewEmployee();">Cancel</button>
            </div> 

        </div>
   </div>

</div>  
</body>
```

Controller Code:

```
 function EmpDetCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.employees = [
   { name: 'A',desg: 'C'}

   ];

   $scope.addNew = function () {
    $scope.employees.push({
        name: $scope.name,desg: $scope.desg
     });
    }

  $scope.ShowAddEmployee= function () {
    return $scope.EmployeeInfoDiv=true;
   }

  $scope.ShowViewEmployee=function () {
      return $scope.EmployeeInfoDiv = false;
  }

}
```

I don't know whether this code is correct or not.
I just tried it.
Can anyone please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code in your 'EmpDetCtrl' controller or create a fiddle for this task ?

Comment: Have a look at the angularjs Todo App. This should do exactly what you want.

Comment: you seem to be doing it right. +1 on the controller code request.

Comment: I have edited the post. Plz check it

Comment: ok, please see updated answer with link to functioning jsfiddle.

Comment: note that your code to show the second div also needs to change fronm ng-show="addEmp" to ng-show="EmployeeInfoDiv".  see the jsfiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-click is updating the EmployeeInfoDiv variable.  So, reference that in ng-show and ng-hide:

```
<div ng-hide="EmployeeInfoDiv" class="container body">
...
<div ng-show="EmployeeInfoDiv" class="popover right EmployeeInfo" style="width:1500px;">
```

You do not need ng-model in the div to make that work.
`ng-model="EmployeeInfoDiv"`

**Update**
A few more issues.  Most important is that (at least in the code posted) MyApp isn't defined anywhere, and your controller is defined on the global scope.  So you need to change your html to:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="EmpDetCtrl"> 
...
```

However, note that this is not the recommended method.  See the angular documentation for [controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wittwerj/xrB77/

Comment: updated with a few corrections to your code needed to get minimal functionality

Comment: Hi, I am doing the same thing...it hides the first div but doesnt show the second div..

Comment: My jsfiddle is working.. we must be doing something differently.  Can you copy your code to a jsfiddle and share the link?